# Python list in lists from datafile with different layouts

Tags: python, list, readline

Im a little stuck here. I'm trying to read a data file in Python 3.
I want to make a list of lists

*The first 36 lines:
each line is a list that's appended to the main list

```
f = open("a.data","r")
h = []
a = []
for word in range(0,797):
    g = f.readline()     
    h.append(g.strip())
    a.append(h)
    h = []
```

But from the 37th line and beyond:
I need a loop where this happens:

The new line is a white line, pass

the next 4 lines should go into a new list 'h' and append to 'h' to 'a'

The thing is that readline() acts crazy for everything I tried

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

ps the strings in the 4 lines are divided by a ;

Comment: It would be helpful to see the file you are trying to read. Also why do you iterate to 797? You should use:  with open('a.data', 'r') as f: g = f.readline().

Comment: "acts crazy"...?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gHKBx9AN

This is the first part of the file. There are 767 datapoints (+36 makes 797)

Comment: Please make a sample, how your data should look like

Comment: This is a handmade sample 
https://pastebin.com/2GunXzB8
Thanks for checking.

@Blackbear, well in a sense that I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

with open('a.data', 'r') as f:
    lst = re.split(';|\n{1,2}', f.read())

length = 36
lstoflst = [lst[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(lst)-1, length)]
print(lstoflst)
```

I read the whole list, split at the newline and semicolon, and make a list of list with a list comprehension.

Please consider a better data format for your next report, like csv if possible.

Comment: That works great!
Let me figure out how. So I can do it myself.
Thank you a lot

Comment: I read the whole file with f.read() After that you have a big string. The elements are delimited with semicolons and newlines. re.split can generate a list of elements, which are delimited by the first argument. '; or \n{1,2}'. The {1,2} is a regex quanitifier for 1 or two newlines. After that, i split the list in slices with a length = 36. So i make a for loop, count from 0 to len(lst) in length steps. So the for loop generates i:0,36,72... After that i put the n elements in a list, the outer [] generates the list of lists

Comment: That's all clear to me. I just don't understand the 1 or 2 lines.

Comment: In your data, there are free lines between your data. This is equal to two \n\n. The single \n is for your list of arguments

Comment: I get the whole code now. Thank you for your support. I really appreciate it.